# Global variable reset to 0

Tags: java, android, debugging

I have a global variable inext set to a random value correctly before a call to setWordsQuestion(). As soon as I enter setWordsQuestion() the value is 0. Do you know how I can debug this?

[image]

and reset to 0:

[image]

Here is the java file:

```
public class ExercisesWords_fragment extends Fragment {
static Context context;
String login;
String fileMenuCard = null;

InputStreamReader isr;
InputStream fIn;
BufferedReader input_card = null;

int level, lang;
int ihelp;

String fileLogin;

RadioGroup rg;
RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3, rb4;
EditText edt;
TextView txt, question;
Button validation, next, help;

int MAXWORDS = 42;
String[] words_questions = new String[MAXWORDS];
String[] words_cb1 = new String[MAXWORDS];
String[] words_cb2 = new String[MAXWORDS];
String[] words_cb3 = new String[MAXWORDS];
String[] words_cb4 = new String[MAXWORDS];
String[] words_response = new String[MAXWORDS];
int[] words_level = new int[MAXWORDS];

int MAXTEMP = 5;
int[] tmp;

int inext_question, inext;

public ExercisesWords_fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.exercises_words_fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    closeFileWords();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

    fileMenuCard = "words";
    login = getArguments().getString("login");
    lang = getArguments().getInt("lang");
    level = getArguments().getInt("level");

    fileLogin = login + "_words.txt";

    initViewFind();
    initExerciseWords();
    nextWordsQuestion();

    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    edt.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
                validateResponse();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    validation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            validateResponse();
        }
    });

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            nextWordsQuestion();
        }
    });

    help.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ihelp = 1;
            hideKeyboard();
            helpWords();
            ihelp = 0;
        }
    });


}

private void drawBTN() {
    if(lang == 0) {
        validation.setText(R.string.pro_validation);
        validation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        next.setText(R.string.next);
        next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        help.setText(R.string.help);
        help.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        validation.setText(R.string.pro_validation_fr);
        validation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        next.setText(R.string.next_fr);
        next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        help.setText(R.string.help_fr);
        help.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}



private void nextWordsQuestion() {
    int inext;
    Random r;
    r = new Random();
    inext = r.nextInt(MAXWORDS);

    if (inext_question < MAXTEMP) {
        tmp[inext_question] = inext;
        inext_question++;

        setWordsQuestion();
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXTEMP; i++) {
        if (inext == tmp[i]) {
            r = new Random();
            inext = r.nextInt(MAXWORDS);
            i--;
        }
    }

    System.arraycopy(tmp, 1, tmp, 0, MAXTEMP - 1);

    tmp[MAXTEMP - 1] = inext;

    setWordsQuestion();
}

private void setWordsQuestion(){
    question.setText(words_questions[inext]);
    question.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    edt.setText("");

    rb1.setText(words_cb1[inext]);
    rb2.setText(words_cb2[inext]);
    rb3.setText(words_cb3[inext]);
    rb4.setText(words_cb4[inext]);

    rb1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    rb2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    rb3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    rb4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    rg.clearCheck();

    hideKeyboard();

}

private void validateResponse(){
    String response;

    if(ihelp == 1){
        int sel = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        if(sel < 0) return;
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) getActivity().findViewById(sel);
        response = rb.getText().toString();
    }
    else {
        response = edt.getText().toString();
    }
    TextView resp = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.resp_words);
    if(response.equals(words_response[inext])) {

        next.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        resp.setText(R.string.resp_card);
        resp.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        resp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
    else {
        resp.setText(R.string.resp_card_no);
        resp.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        resp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}

private void helpWords(){
    hideKeyboard();

    rb1.setText(words_cb1[inext]);
    rb1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    rb2.setText(words_cb2[inext]);
    rb2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    rb3.setText(words_cb3[inext]);
    rb3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    rb4.setText(words_cb4[inext]);
    rb4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}

private void hideKeyboard(){
    EditText e = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.words_answer);
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(e.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

private void openWords(){
    String l = null;
    try {
        if (lang == 0)
            fIn = context.getResources().getAssets()
                    .open(fileMenuCard+".txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        else
            fIn = context.getResources().getAssets()
                    .open(fileMenuCard+"_fr.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
        input_card = new BufferedReader(isr);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }

    for(int i=0;i<MAXWORDS;i++){
        try {
            l = input_card.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (l != null) {
            StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(l, ";");
            words_questions[i] = tokens.nextToken();
            words_level[i] = Integer.valueOf(tokens.nextToken());
            words_cb1[i] = tokens.nextToken();
            words_cb2[i] = tokens.nextToken();
            words_cb3[i] = tokens.nextToken();
            words_cb4[i] = tokens.nextToken();
            words_response[i] = tokens.nextToken();
         }
    }
}

private void closeFileWords(){
    try {
        fIn.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        isr.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        input_card.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void initExerciseWords(){
    tmp = new int[MAXTEMP];

    for(int i=0;i<MAXTEMP;i++)
        tmp[i] = -1;

    inext_question = 0;

    openWords();

}

private void initViewFind(){
    edt = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.words_answer);
    txt = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.title_words);
    validation = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.validation_words);
    next = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.next_words);
    help = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.help_words);
    question = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.words_question);
    rg = (RadioGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rg_words);
    rb1 = (RadioButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.radio1_words);
    rb2 = (RadioButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.radio2_words);
    rb3 = (RadioButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.radio3_words);
    rb4 = (RadioButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.radio4_words);

    if(lang == 0)
        txt.setText(R.string.words_fr);
    else
        txt.setText(R.string.words_title_fr);

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting a local variable that hides the instance member :

```
private void nextWordsQuestion() {
    int inext; // remove this line
    ...
    inext = r.nextInt(MAXWORDS);
    ...
    setWordsQuestion();
    ...
}
```

Therefore `setWordsQuestion`, which uses the instance member, doesn't see the value you set in `nextWordsQuestion`.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a random value to inext, you are assigning it to a local variable, not the global one.

To fix, simply remove the local variable.

```
    private void nextWordsQuestion() {
//int inext;
Random r;
r = new Random();
inext = r.nextInt(MAXWORDS);

if (inext_question < MAXTEMP) {
    tmp[inext_question] = inext;
    inext_question++;

    setWordsQuestion();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Bummer! I must have had dust in my eyes!